# C# WPF Фокусирование окна

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть окно с кастомным Window Chrome сделаном на Grid которая обрабатывает два события:

```
private void OnTitleBarMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  switch(e.LeftButton) {
    case MouseButtonState.Pressed: {
      this.DragMove();
      break;
    }
  }
}


private void OnTitleBarMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
  switch(e.LeftButton) {
    case MouseButtonState.Pressed: {
      var point = this.PointToScreen(e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this));
      this.Left = point.X - (this.RestoreBounds.Width * 0.55);
      this.Top = point.Y - 20;
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
      this.DragMove();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

и получается если вне окна зажать ЛКМ е вести на TitleBar окна оно начнет DragMove

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать чтобы окно двигалось только тогда когда оно в фокусе?

Comment: @АндрейNOP какие? как? я решил немного проблему проверкой на IsFocused

Comment: Не, я проверил, на самом деле вообще достаточно просто подписаться на `MouseLeftButtonDown` и вызвать там `DragMove();`, больше никакой код писать не надо

Comment: @АндрейNOP проверка на Pressed должна быть иначе Exception при Release в DragMove

Comment: ну да, Move у меня для окна в maximized, чтобы мышкой потащить и Normal стало

Comment: вот это `OnTitleBarMouseMove` определенно лишнее

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой минимальный код работает у меня:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" Width="300" Height="200">

    <Grid>
        <Grid Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <TextBlock Text="Header" Foreground="Yellow" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragMove();
    }
}
```

Ничего дополнительно писать не требуется